# I am trying to get a value the i just want the last date and time only

Tags: shell-script, sed, grep, array

Trying to get a value date and time not the whole log

${1} - Command Line Arguments in Bash

${i} - Array Item in for Loop

```
grep -ERh "stopped" ems_*/SystemOut*.log | tail -1
```

Now the value is like that

```
ems_inet1/SystemOut1.log:[6/8/17 10:47:45:896 SGT] 00000066 ServerCollabo A   WSVR0024I: Server ems_inet1 stopped
```

In some code has multiple value in the square bracket

```
ems_inet1/SystemOut1.log:[9/24/19 17:23:34:324 SGT] 00004442 SystemOut O 24 Sep 2019 17:23:34:324 [INFO] [ems_inet1] [CID-UIASYNC-16412]
```

Tried RegEx on sed it does not work well

```
\[\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3}\s+\w{3}\]
```

I just want this value

```
[6/8/17 10:47:45:896 SGT]
```

It solve by @Bodo

Comment: What is `$1` and  `$i`? Please edit your question to include this.

Comment: You could just append an `| grep -o '\[.*\]'`, but depending on your input, there may be more elegant solutions.

Comment: We can't help you parse data you don't show. We know that `$1` is the argument, the question is _what is the argument_? And _what is the value of $i_? Please [edit] your question and show us: i) a few lines of your input file and ii) the output you require from that input file as well as iii) the value of `$1`.

Comment: If `${i}` is a single item you won't have got the filename listed at the beginning. Are you sure it has the value you think it should have?

Comment: I have multiple files to check

Comment: DO you have only `ems_inet1/SystemOut1.log:[6/8/17 10:47:45:896 SGT]` pattern in each line?

Comment: Please show us your actual data! We cannot help if we need to guess what the data look like. For example, you probably want `grep -oP 'stopped.*\K\[.+?\]`, but we can't know unless you show us.

Comment: So does `${i}` contain multiple file names? If that's the case it's not good script coding practice, and it also means that `ems_inet1/SystemOut1.log:` must not be considered part of the pattern space. (I'd also infer that your loop isn't really looping.)

Comment: Please show us a proper source line and the corresponding output. We're trying to understand which bits are in your source, which are being added by your usage of `grep`, and which aren't required. There are `....` in the supposed source. Does that mean _more text follows here_, or that there are multiple lines, or ... what exactly?

Comment: Probably the match pattern `"stopped"` is found in the data you replaced by some dots. Otherwise this output would not match the `grep` command. Without the correct data it is difficult to help.

Comment: msp9011 - yes every line have this data and time.

Comment: roaima - `...` means that there is all other information and in different folder

Comment: @ChanChan You should add all clarifying information to the question, as far as it is still relevant after your edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the complete actual data this answer is based on some guessing.

I assume that

- your filenames don't contain brackets (`[]`) and
- your data always contains a time stamp in brackets at the beginning of the line and

You can post-process your output with `sed`
(Edit: Modified regex to catch the first group in brackets in case there are more.)

```
grep -ER "stopped" ems_rpt1/SystemOut.log | tail -1 | sed 's/[^[]*\(\[[^]]*\]\).*/\1/'
```

Note: You use option `-E` which means "Match using extended regular expressions." In your example have use a simple string only, so you could use option `-F` instead of `-E`, which would mean "Match using fixed strings."

Comment: I _think_ that the OP wants to lose unspecified trailing text after the closing `]`. But I really can't be sure as it's not at all clear in the question.

Comment: @roaima You are right, I missed that the example output contains some dots and the desired output does not.

Comment: It's not at all clear is it :-(

Comment: @Bodo The parse is wrong

Comment: @ChanChan I fixed the missing closing parenthesis

Comment: @ChanChan I edited the regex to catch the first part in brackets. (You should have shown more different sample lines in your question.)